# python-mode indentation not working upon hitting enter

Tags: python, emacs, python-mode

I just installed `python-mode` from ELPA and when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> the cursor goes straight to the beginning of the next line. For instance for the following code:

```
def hello_world():
    print "hello world!"
    for i in range(3):
        print "hello again"
    return 0
```

I have to hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> after <kbd>Enter</kbd> every time after I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to a new-line (although interestingly <kbd>TAB</kbd> sends the cursor to the right place).

When I installed `python-mode` I got some warning messages relating to indentation which I don't really understand, [here is a link to those warning messages](https://gist.github.com/vellamike/6244872#file-warnings).

Comment: that last edit should be in the answers section(by adding your own answer), not the part of the original question.

Comment: you might as well want to bring back the link to the "warning message", which you accidentally removed in your last edit ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>C-j</kbd> is the key I was looking for ('newline-and-indent' command). I managed to rebind <kbd>Enter</kbd> to this by putting the following hook in my init.el:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (define-key python-mode-map "\r" 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Comment: just for people copy-pasting the piece of code from here: it's missing one ')' from the end, which makes emacs complain about malformed init file.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you installed python-mode, since Emacs comes with Python support built-in, but I don't think this affects the rest.  If you want RET to indent after inserting a the newline, you probably like that everywhere, so you might like to enable `electric-indent-mode`.

Comment: cheers for the tip - My emacs version didn't have python-mode so I installed it.

Comment: Are you sure?  Emacs has had built-in support for Python since Emacs-22.

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>C-j</kbd> instead of <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Actually, <kbd>C-j</kbd> is bound to [`(newline-and-indent)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Indent.html), which does the two steps(<kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>)mentioned in the question.

As of version 24.4.50.1 the default behavior has been reversed i.e <kbd>enter</kbd> adds newline and indent if needed while <kbd>C-j</kbd> doesn't. Although the functions these key-bindings map to aren't as mentioned above.

Comment: @MikeVella if enter did what C-j does i would find that kind of awkward. although it was otherwise at first but later on seemed logically to me.

Comment: OK, I found a discussion about C-j does in the source code. Now I'm going to try and rebind RET to C-j.

Comment: @MikeVella I suggest you make a habit of using `C-j` for the purpose, because that way you wouldn't be a searching for a key that gives you an indentation-free-newline, having to use `M-x newline` and other not-so-simple ways of doing so.

Comment: @hus784 'newline-and-indent' does a really good job of guessing which line of indentation I want (e.g indenting after a : but not after a print statement") So I'm happy to rebind RET to that.